# Symfony Routing; Internal URIs in User Generated Content

Tags: routes, symfony1

I am working on a Symfony (1.4) project which requires the user to be able to insert Internal URIs into the body of user generated content, writing within TinyMCE/WMD editor (haven't decided yet!) the user can add an internal URI to another place on the website. The content will be stored in the database as markdown/html.

I could simply insert the current URI retrieved through Symfony itself, but I was hoping there was a way to store the respective module/action/etc variables so that if the route needed to change, the URIs would remain correct throughout the website.

The only thing I can think of is a processor much like PHP Markdown, which performs a text search, extracting a custom mark-up within the content block, and replacing it with the markdown/html code for the generated route (using Symfony's get_url()/link_to() methods). [This would also require a text-mark-up generator, etc.]

Does Symfony have any other/better way than this? Can I access Symfony helpers/etc from within user generated input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this. The best way is likely:

- Parse the editor input on submission to find all URLs.
- Replace URLs with a custom syntax that stores route name and parameters.
- Whenever retrieving/displaying the information, remove your custom syntax and replace it with the generated route (e.g. via a preg_replace callback)

Alternatively, for small sites with relatively inflexible routes, it may be possible to display a drop-down list of available routes.

Either route will probably involve some headaches.

Comment: Yeah, I thought as much. Thanks for your suggestions. Unless someone comes up with some magic soon, that will have to be that!

Answer (score 0):

just tell users that they need to use named routes `@my_custom_url` and define them in symfony routing file `routing.yml`

Comment: Wouldn't a name route still need to be processed by a Symfony method? The following would not work, I don't think; <a href="/@default?module=job&action=show&id=1">Job 1</a>

Comment: yeap right, somehow i thought that you are parsing them and you just don't want to have module/action typing by users